# Searching for a python memory profiler that gives method information

Tags: python, memory, profiling

Is there a Python memory profiler that gives the memory usage for each method/function rather than line-by-line?
Reason I am looking for a memory leak, but I am not sure where to look for it. The program is much to large for a line profiler.

--

when using cProfile, we get information how long each method runs. Is it possible to have similar profiling for the memory.

Comment: Isn't this question little off-topic about **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource**?

Answer (score 1):

Try `memprof` It logs the memory usage of all the variables during the execution of the decorated methods.
.

```
from memprof import *

@memprof
def my_func():
    a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_func()
```